# ¿Alguien sabe por qué me marca error al declalar el bucle WHILE?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[![No entiendo porque me marca error al declarar el bucle `WHILE`, estoy usando MySQL 8.0.19 y como gesto MySQL Workbench.
Si alguien me pudiera explicar cual es mi error se los agradecería mucho.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMH9y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMH9y.png)

El codigo es:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()

BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

    WHILE v1 > 0 DO

      SET v1 = v1-1;

    END WHILE;
END;
```

El error es:

```
"WHILE" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, BEGIN, CACHE, CHECKSUM, COMMIT, DEALLOCATE, ...
```

Comment: Consejo: cuando hagas una pregunta no pongas solo la imagen, coloca tu codigo en el formato debido y ademas de eso tambien pon el error para que se pueda reproducir y visualizar de forma correcta, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que si estas haciendo tu `Stored Procedure` de forma manual debes poner de forma explicita los delimitadores y la base de datos que vas a ocupar, mas o menos deberia quedar de esta manera

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `dataBase`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO

    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

O bien en la parte izquierda de workbench (si lo tienes como viene por defecto) vas a tener la lista de tablas y elementos de una BD, mas o menos deberia aparecer algo asi:

```
-Database
--Tables
--Views
--Stored Procedures
--Functions
```

Si le das click derecho a `Stored Procedures` te va a aparecer la opcion `Create stored procedure` y ahi si puedes poner el codigo directamente como lo tienes.

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, me sirvió tu respuesta.